# How to Join with Native SQL Query and doctrine

Tags: sql, doctrine-orm, query-builder, entitymanager, native-sql

I'm developping an application with symfony 3.4. I want to execute a specific query. So i have two entities: the first is `PrPurchaseRequest`. the second is `PrSpecificFieldValue`.
 `PrPurchaseRequest` has `oneToMany` `prSpecificFieldValues`.

> I want to get id of purchaseRequest and prSpecificFieldValues

i did that

```
 $queryBuilder = $this->getEntityManager()->createQuery('select p.id as purchaseId, pr.keyField AS keyField,pr.ID AS prkeyvalueid from '.PrPurchaseRequest::class. ' p LEFT JOIN '. PrSpecificFieldValue::class .' spec ON p.id = spec.purchaseId ');
```

and that didn't work for me

> [Syntax Error] Error: Expected end of string, got
>   'ON'

how can i do it

Comment: Instead of `ON` use `WITH`. https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/query-builder.html#high-level-api-methods

Answer (score -1):

Using doctrine you need to play around your entities and their mappings with other entities   in order to relate them like

```
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;

/** @Entity */
class PrPurchaseRequest
{
    /**
     * 
     * @OneToMany(targetEntity="PrSpecificFieldValue", mappedBy="prPurchaseRequest")
     */
    private $prSpecificFieldValues;
    // ...

    public function __construct() {
        $this->prSpecificFieldValues = new ArrayCollection();
    }
}

/** @Entity */
class PrSpecificFieldValue
{
    /**
     *
     * @ManyToOne(targetEntity="PrPurchaseRequest", inversedBy="prSpecificFieldValues")
     * @JoinColumn(name="pr_purchase_request_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $prPurchaseRequest;
}
```

Now you have defined relationship between your entities you can join them based on their mapping (prSpecificFieldValues defined on PrPurchaseRequest class ) like

Its DQL **(DQL != SQL)**

```
SELECT p,v
FROM PrPurchaseRequest p
JOIN p.prSpecificFieldValues v
```

No need to specify `ON` clause doctrine will handle this for you.

[**One-To-Many, Bidirectional**](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/association-mapping.html#one-to-many-bidirectional)

Comment: thanks for repling but this query get all other join tables. but i want only prSpecificFieldValues

Comment: @Ld91 you can refer you properties in select list if you don't want all data like `select p, v.keyField AS keyField,v.ID AS prkeyvalueid ..`